# Why does a unary operator enable a ()=>X implicit conversion?

Tags: scala

I encounter an issue that an implicit `()=>X` conversion happens when I define and use a unary operator. Below is a minimal example:

```
class Gate {
  def unary_!(): Gate = this
}

class Foo {
  private def foo(f: () => Gate) = 1
  val gate = new Gate

  // Compiles, -Xprint:typer shows it becomes
  //   Foo.this.foo({
  //     (() => Foo.this.gate.unary_!())
  //   })
  foo(!gate)

  // Does not compile, we get
  //  error: type mismatch;
  //  found   : Gate
  //  required: () => Gate
  //  foo(gate)
  foo(gate)
}
```

Where does this `() => Gate` conversion happens and why does it only happen with `unary_!`?

---

**Edited**

Thanks for the answer! I raised this question because the Eta expansion (from `X` to `() => X` blocks another implicit conversion we defined for `X` and wanted to happen. Removing the unnecessary parentheses from `unary_!` solves the problem for us. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think this is an implicit conversion when you are explicitly writing `!gate` and not `gate` ?

Comment: This is same as writing `-5` instead of `5`. Which applies unary operator `-` on integer `5`. This is probably done by using `reflection` on the argument of the unary operator and the respective function is then applied. And this has nothing to do with `implicit` in any way.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh, I am referring to the argument of function foo. Notice that it takes a ()=>Gate, but I am calling it with Gate.

Comment: Well.... one thing in functional programming is `expressions`. Here... every expression thing like `"abdd"` is actually a block `() => String`. Which is somewhat explained as an `eta-expansion` of `expressions`

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh No, but see my answer. That 6.26 is about implicit conversions, built-in or as it were implicit, some of which behave in the obvious way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just eta-expansion, which turns a method into a function.

http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#eta-expansion

The trigger is that the expected type is a function.

The link is ambiguous in the spec, but the expansion is at 6.26.5.

Compare these two forms:

```
scala> foo(gate.unary_!())
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Gate
 required: () => Gate
              foo(gate.unary_!())
                              ^

scala> foo(gate.unary_!)
res3: Int = 1
```

The first case is an application of the function. Doesn't type check.

What is the second case? Instead of adding parens implicitly to turn it into an application, it will first eta-expand to make a function, which type checks.

It's been suggested that adding parens ("empty application" in the spec) should come first, so that it would behave the same as the first case.

Here's the spec wording for how the prefix op is handled:

http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#prefix-operations

> A prefix operation op;e consists of a prefix operator op, which must
>   be one of the identifiers ‘+’, ‘-’, ‘!’ or ‘~’. The expression op;e is
>   equivalent to the postfix method application e.unary_op.

But this example shows that it's a member selection, but not an application.

Here's the counterexample without parens on your method definition:

```
scala> class Gate { def unary_! : Gate = this }
defined class Gate

scala> def foo(f: () => Gate) = 1
foo: (f: () => Gate)Int

scala>   val gate = new Gate
gate: Gate = Gate@2db0f6b2

scala> foo(!gate)
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Gate
 required: () => Gate
              foo(!gate)
                  ^
```

There you get simple evaluation first, the first conversion in 6.26.2.

More examples [on the related ticket](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7187).

A comment there on a linked ticket suggests not only changing the order of implicits, but disabling eta-expansion for this case:

> I'd be inclined to go further and deprecate eta-expansion given an
>   expected type of Function0, and avoid triggering it with SAM types of
>   the same shape from the outset.

Which is too bad, because this would have made a nice little puzzler.

Comment: I have difficulty understanding the spec, and wonder if there is a simpler explanation regarding how the negation makes a difference?